# Finding Thailand Trek Guide (Khao Chang Puak and Sun Nhok Wua)

Tags: online-resources, thailand, trekking

Me and my friends would like to trek in Khao Chang Puak or Sun Nhok Wua. However, we can't seem to find any information on the internet as to how we find trek guides and stuff as this will be our first time trekking in Thailand. We have difficulty reading from most sites like the national park ones as we cannot read Thai.

Hence, we would like to ask for your advice on what we could do about this?

Answer (score 1):

Both trips are best done as overnight trips, camping in the parks.  So you need in addition to a guide, camping gear, food, water, etc.

Best bet is to search for trekking tours and guides in Kanchanaburi, as it is the closest city with tourist services.  There are a number of companies there, but you will need to contact them about custom tours, as the destinations are not widely known, thus not widely sought after.